# Retirar aspas de array com duas posições

Tags: javascript

Olá, 
Alguém poderia me ajudar, estou tentando retirar as aspas de um array com duas posições em javascript. Algo como:

`["1", "2"]`

Passar a ser:

`[1, 2]`

Answer (score 3):

Você quer converter todos os valores em número? Pode usar o método [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) da array para isso:

```
let lista = ["1", "2"].map( s => Number(s) );
```

Comment: Boa @bfavaretto!